# Presenting modal view controller from popover

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad, uiviewcontroller, uipopovercontroller

I have a view controller that is inside a popover, and I want to present a modal view controller from it. Here's my code:

```
EditDateViewController *dateViewController = [[EditDateViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"EditDateViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:dateViewController];
    navController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
    [self presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];
    [dateViewController release];
    [navController release];
```

The result is this:

[alt text http://cl.ly/5300e4f8f5d440d3f850/content](http://cl.ly/5300e4f8f5d440d3f850/content)

For some reason, the navigation bar background is transparent (or black?) even though I did not configure it that way. I tried manually setting the `tintColor` property of the navigation bar in the `viewDidLoad` method of the modal view controller, but it had no effect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
dateViewController.modalInPopover=YES;

self.navigationController.modalInPopover=YES;
```